# Are javascript property names like "__proto__" not standardized in ES5/6?

Tags: javascript, syntax, properties, prototype, standards

There're some properties in js starts/ends with double underscores like `__proto__`. But I know it equals to constructor.prototype, right? I wish to know whether ES5/ES6 standard included these **xxx**_ property names, or they're just implementation specific keywords, might have different behavior in different implementations?

Plus: where can I check if a keyword is part of ES standard?

Comment: It's not equal to `prototype`. `__proto__` contains reference to object prototype. `prototype` contains object that will be prototype of instances which this constructor creates. Constructor itself has different prototype (you can check constructor's `__proto__` for this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know it equals to constructor.prototype, right?

[No](https://stackoverflow.com/q/650764/1048572).

> I wish to know whether ES5/ES6 standard included these `__xxx__` property names, or they're just implementation specific keywords, might have different behavior in different implementations?

You can find an overview in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), there are `__count__`, `__noSuchMethod__`, `__parent__`, `__proto__`, `__defineGetter__`, `__defineSetter__`, `__lookupGetter__`, and `__lookupSetter__`; and **all of them are deprecated**. Other implementations than Gecko might have featured more.

Only the getter/setter methods and `__proto__` were common amongst implementations, and only [`__proto__` got into the compatibilty section of the ES6 standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061819/1048572).

> where can I check if a keyword is part of ES stardard, any recommended web-sites?

Just read [the standards themselves](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262-arch.htm)!