# Factory functions vs Object.create - JavaScript - when to use which

Tags: javascript

I have been reading much about object composition in JavaScript and the advantages of this pattern over the 'class' pattern. I have seen examples of the composition that demonstrate using `Object.create()` to create new objects and other examples that demonstration using factory functions that return objects.

Object.create example:

```
var Component = {
  init: function() {
    // do stuff
  }
};

var button = Object.create(Component);

button.init();
```

Factory function example:

```
var ComponentFactory = function() {
   return {
     init: function() {
       // do stuff
     }
  }
}

var button = ComponentFactory();

button.init();
```

I understand that factory functions are intended for abstracting away complexity involved in creating objects, however I am trying to understand if there is any practical difference between `Object.create()` and a function which returns an object.

Comment: It's not either-or. You should use [both together](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39546963/1048572).

Comment: The whole point of a factory function (or constructor, for that matter) is that you should not need a `.init()` method!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factory functions create objects with its own properties, `Object.create` creates objects with assigned [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

In your example, every object created by `ComponentFactory` has its own `init` (reference to different location in memory),  `Object.create(Component)` creates objects reference to the same prototype(`Component`)

`Object.create` costs less space/memory, since it doesn't create properties. Use this for the common part of objects.

Factory functions are more flexible, can create objects with initial data, and local variables in [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). Use this for custom part of objects.

```
const Component = {init() {}}
const x = Object.create(Component)
const y = Object.create(Component)

console.log(x.init === y.init) //true


function createComponent(data) {
  return {
    init() { return data }
  }
}

const p = createComponent('a')
const q = createComponent('b')
console.log(p.init === q.init) //false
console.log(p.init()) //a
console.log(q.init()) //b
```

Answer (score 2):

**I. Object.create**

`Object.create` create object from prototype given in attribute, so if We check `hasOwnProperty` on object created from `Object.create` we will see that it has no properties ( every one is in his prototype ).

So every object created by `Object.create(SomeObj)` is linked with the same prototype, this has some consequences, for example complex objects in prototype can be changed on every instance and change is visible on other instances.

**Conclusion - Object.create is something similar to inheritance.**

Example code to show what I am talking about:

```js
var obj={

    complexProp:{
        name:"John",
        surname:"Doe"
    },
    hello:function(){
    
      console.log("Hello "+this.complexProp.name+" "+this.complexProp.surname);

    }

};

var objA=Object.create(obj);
var objB=Object.create(obj);

console.log(objA.hasOwnProperty("complexProp"));//false

objA.complexProp.surname="Smith";//change in objA

objB.hello();//so we see that change is also in objB
```

**II. Factory**

Second example is creating objects on the fly, so every object is new instance, **no connection between objects**. Second solution also give us closure , so we can create some private variables or functions visible only for our object. Private variable usage:

```
var ComponentFactory = function(surname) {

   var name="John";//local variable visible for object

   return {
     init: function() {
     // do stuff
     //variable name is visible in object
     //variable surname is also visible from object

     }
  }
}
```

Comment: can we use Object.freeze in the Object.create to avoid the change in the other instances?.like this
`complexProp: Object.freeze({ name:"John", surname:"Doe"})`

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned, Object.create() allows you to create objects that have some relationship, while Function factories don't. I would actually argue that Object.create is a form of factory function, only that the function is bound to creating objects with the same properties. Consider these two scenarios:

Object.create:

```js
const Staff = {
    setUp: function(name, idno){
        this.name = name;
        this.idno = idno;
        this.office = "Unallocated"
        this.category = "Staff";
        this.accomodation = ""
            
        }
    };

    james = Object.create(Staff);
    james.setUp("James Black", 1)
    console.log(james.name) //James Black
    console.log(james.idno) //1

//Now let's assume that we want to change something about the 10,000 staff that //we recruit and sack every year. One condition is that all our staff are 20 //years old.

we simply say*/

    Staff.age = 20
    console.log(james.age)//20
```

As you can see, you can change the property of all members of a group by simply changing the parent object. If however you are using a function factory that simply creates unique objects each time, you won't be able to do this.