# How does __proto__ work when object is created with Object.create(null)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototype-chain

Consider the following javascript code

```
var a = Object.create(null);
a.foo = 1;
var b = Object.create(a);
console.log(b.foo);  //prints 1
console.log(b.__proto__);  //prints undefined
b.__proto__ = null;
console.log(b.__proto__);  //prints null
console.log(b.foo);  //prints 1
```

Can anyone explain how object `b` is accessing the "foo" property of `a` even after setting `b.__proto__` to null? What is the internal link which is used to access the property of `a`?

I tried searching through SO for possible explanations but couldn't find any explanation for this particular behaviour of Javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061819/1048572) [`__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), which is a getter/setter on `Object.prototype` - but your objects don't inherit from that, so it's `undefined` at first and the assignment creates a standard property with the name `__proto__`.

Use the proper [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)/[`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) instead and the code will do what you expect:

```
var a = Object.create(null);
a.foo = 1;
var b = Object.create(a);
console.log(b.foo); // 1
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(b)); // {foo:1} - a
Object.setPrototypeOf(b, null);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(b)); // null
console.log(b.foo); // undefined
```

Comment: Thanks. You answered the first question. Can you explain how the inheritance is working in my code? It's not working through the `__proto__` for sure.

Comment: @Priyanjit In your version, `a` keeps being the [[prototype]] of `b`.

Comment: How's that happening? Is there any hidden property other than `__proto__`? Because `a` and `b` are two different objects.

Comment: It happened right when you used `Object.create`. Notice that `__proto__` is not a "hidden property" (ok, it's nonenumerable, but that's not what we mean). The prototype chain link - denoted [[prototype]] - is an [internal slot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33075262/1048572), which is truly "hidden" and *not a property*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Bergi

Comment: @Bergi But if you remove the null in the first line then it is working fine. Any reason for that. And that is also not a browser/engine specific.

Comment: @AyanPal Sure, `Object.create` can also create objects that do inherit from `Object.prototype`, including the `__proto__` behaviour

Comment: @Bergi what happens when I set to `__proto__ = null`? Why I can't to reset for `__proto__` value?

Comment: @MaximPro What do you mean by "*can't reset*"? Using the `__proto__` setter to set the [[prototype]] to `null` just does that. Of course afterwards, the object doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype` any more, loosing the `__proto__` property…

Comment: @Bergi I mean it how reinstall (reset)

Comment: @MaximPro `Object.setPrototypeOf(x, Object.prototype)` (or whatever it was before). Doesn't my answer say so?

Comment: @Bergi no, I talking about this: `var a = new Object; a.__proto__; ///true proto, created by engine` `a.__proto__ = null; /// delete __proto__???` `a.__proto__ = Object.prototype; /// false proto, creates simple property by user`

Comment: @MaximPro yes, that's exactly what my answer explains. Don't use the deprecated `__proto__` property, especially not on objects that don't inherit from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @Bergi I fully understand your answer. But when we write so `a.__proto__ = null` what happens? Is it somewhere described? Just after `null`, it's unclear how the engine behaves. I mean that `a.__proto__ = Object.prototype` is not a prototype.

Comment: Yes, it is described, go read the ES6 spec. When you do `a.__proto__ = null` then `a` becomes an object without a prototype, i.e. the [[prototype]] slot is null. It looks like it was created by `Object.create(null)`.

Comment: @Bergi Well, then why can not we put the prototype back, for example, so `a.__proto__ = Object.prototype` (it's supposed to set `[[Prototype]]` to `Object.prototype`). Why does not it work and create a user property?

Comment: @MaximPro "*`__proto__` is a getter/setter on Object.prototype - but your objects don't inherit from that, so it's undefined*". There is nothing magic about this property. When it doesn't exist, it doesn't exist. A setter that does not exist is not supposed to set [[prototype]].

Comment: @Bergi Hmm it turns out that when we put `null` for `__proto__` we cut off the inheritance and accordingly cut off getter and setter and therefore we can not put any prototype back in place. Right?

Comment: @MaximPro That's what I've been saying all the time. Putting `null` in [[prototype]] of course cuts of the inheritance chain, isn't that the purpose you intended in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi So, I understood correctly this? I do not know for me this moment was difficult to understand.

Comment: @MaximPro Right.

Answer (score 2):

Answer by @Bergi is correct. Here is in-depth answer what is happening in case of `__proto__`

```
var a = Object.create({});
var b = Object.create(a);
b.__proto__===a; //true
var c = Object.create(null);
var d = Object.create(c);
d.__proto__===c; //false..confusion

Object.hasOwnProperty.call(d,"__proto__"); //false as expected
Object.hasOwnProperty.call(b,"__proto__"); //false ?

Object.hasOwnProperty.call(Object,"__proto__"); //false
Object.hasOwnProperty.call(Object.prototype,"__proto__"); //true
```

Which means `__proto__` is only present in `Object.prototype`.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype,"__proto__")
//{enumerable: false, configurable: true, get: ƒ, set: ƒ}
```

`__proto__` is a getter setter which should return internal link to object parent something like

```
get __proto__(){return this.hidden_internal_link_to_parent;}
```

Case `b.__proto__`:- `b` doesn't have `__proto__` property so it goes through `[[prototype]]` chain to `a`, then to `a`'s parent and at last to `Object.prototype`. `Object.prototype` have `__proto__` and it returns link of `b`'s parent which is `a`.

Case `d.__proto__`:- `d`'s link to `Object.prototype` is  broken (d --parent-->c and c--parent-->null). So `d.__proto__` is undefined. But `d` have internal link to `c` which can be accessed by `Object.getPrototypeOf(d)`.