# Why does Object.seal allow user setters to still work, but disables native setters like __proto__?

Tags: javascript

For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55678953), I had assumed that `__proto__` being a setter would mean that `Object.seal` would not change the behavior of the `__proto__` setter, but I was mistaken.

But, this doesn't work with regular setters, for example:

```js
var o = {
 get foo() { return this._foo },
 set foo(val) { this._foo = val },
}

o.foo = 5

Object.seal(o)

o.foo = 10 // it still works!

console.log(o.foo)
console.log(o._foo)

// but this doesn't work:
o.__proto__ = { n: 5 }

console.log(o.n)
```

Are users who write setters expected to check sealed/frozen/extensible state? It doesn't seem like many people do this in practice. Shouldn't Object.seal then disable a setter, like it does with `__proto__`?

So, the question is, is there a special case for `__proto__` (etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `__proto__` setter makes the engine *internally* call the `SetPrototypeOf` procedure. From the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-additional-properties-of-the-object.prototype-object):

> B.2.2.1.2 set Object.prototype.**proto**
>
> The value of the [[Set]] attribute is a built-in function that takes an argument proto. It performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Let O be RequireObjectCoercible(this value).
> 2. ReturnIfAbrupt(O).
> 3. If Type(proto) is neither Object nor Null, return undefined.
> 4. If Type(O) is not Object, return undefined.
> 5. Let status be O.[SetPrototypeOf].
> 6. ReturnIfAbrupt(status).
> 7. If status is false, throw a TypeError exception.

If the object is sealed, the `SetPrototypeOf` call returns false, [because](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-setprototypeof-v):

> 5. If extensible is false, return false.

Setters which *don't* attempt to call `setPrototypeOf` (internally or externally) will not throw an error. `Object.seal` does not prevent setters from being called, but it prevents setters which actually try to **add new properties** (or change the object's prototype) from succeeding. Because your custom setter doesn't try to add new properties, no error is thrown; the `_foo` property is put onto the object *before* it is sealed.

If you had called the setter for the first time *after* the object was sealed, *before* `_foo` had been added, you would've seen an error in strict mode:

```js
'use strict';
var o = {
  get foo() {
    return this._foo
  },
  set foo(val) {
    this._foo = val
  },
}

Object.seal(o)

o.foo = 10
```

In non-strict mode, assigning a new property to a sealed object will fail silently (but trying to change the prototype will throw an error):

```js
var o = {
  get foo() {
    return this._foo
  },
  set foo(val) {
    this._foo = val
  },
}

Object.seal(o)

o.foo = 10
console.log(o.foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sealing the object locks in the internal *[[prototype]]* link. You can't change it any more, regardless trough which method:

```
> Object.setPrototypeOf(Object.seal({}), {})
VM2817:1 Uncaught TypeError: #<Object> is not extensible
    at Function.setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:8
```

This has nothing to do with getters/setters.