# Using `__proto__` in object literals

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, inheritance, v8

If I am not mistaken, using `Object.setPrototypeOf()` and `__proto__` to change object prototype is considered deprecated as a "very slow operation". Also, [IIRC](https://benediktmeurer.de/2018/08/16/javascript-engine-fundamentals-optimizing-prototypes/), this can degrade the performance of objects in V8.

Also, it is usually not recommended to add properties to an object after creation as it can degrade the performance of objects in V8 as well (if I understand correctly explanations like [this](https://benediktmeurer.de/2018/06/14/javascript-engine-fundamentals-shapes-and-inline-caches/)).

So, if I need to create an object with defined prototype AND properties, I have two options:

1. `Object.create()` with both prototype and property descriptors arguments set. This is rather cumbersome way.
2. Object literal with `__proto__` and properties.

So the questions: are these two options equal with regard to performance? Or is the second way is just syntactical sugar for the same postponed `Object.setPrototypeOf()` operation internally? Has the second way any drawbacks? Are these drawbacks implementation-dependent or common (spec-dependent?)?

**UPD**

See also discussions in cross-posts:

https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2901

https://twitter.com/vsemozhetbyt/status/1292057058213269504

A naive benchmark: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2901#issuecomment-671027781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any drawbacks to using `__proto__` in an object literal.

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

> That syntax is standard and optimized for in implementations, and quite different from `Object.prototype.__proto__`.

`Object.prototype.__proto__` is deprecated but `__proto__` in an object literal is not. `__proto__` in an object literal was made standard in ES6 and was already supported by browsers such as Internet Explorer as far back as ES5. It was part of Annex B but [it's being moved into the main spec](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/2125).

Answer (score 0):

"`__proto__` is slow" is the wrong information. Internally when you create an object, it has [[Prototype]] property which is set to its prototype.

```
function Product(price,title){

  this.Price = price; 
  this.Title  = title; 

}

 Product.prototype.owner = "foo";

 let p1 = new Product(10, "pen");

 p1.__proto__ === Product.prototype; // true
```

So if you want to create an object from another object literal, you have only two choices either use `Object.create` or manually set `__proto__`.

Another option is to use constructors, as I showed above

Answer (score 0):

No, [`__proto__` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061819/1048572) because it should not be part of the language (but stays for backcompat).

On the other hand, `setPrototypeOf` is not deprecated but merely despised because of [its performance impact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23809148/1048572). However, it's not much of a problem to call it on *fresh* objects, there's nothing to deoptimise yet and the object usages will be optimised with regard to the new prototype.

However, there's a much simpler way: combine `Object.create` with `Object.assign`:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf({…}, proto)

Object.assign(Object.create(proto), {…})
```