# Difference between __proto__ and prototype

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clarify the differences of both `prototype` and `__proto__`.  Does `__proto__` always point to the parent's `prototype`?

So `Array.prototype` would include methods like `concat()`, etc.
and `Array.__proto__` would point to the methods on the parent/base object of Array?

Comment: Best thing to do is to stop wondering about `__proto__` entirely, as it's a deprecated feature. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` instead.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "parent", so I'll go out on a limb and say *No*.

Answer (score 2):

### TL:DR

`__proto__` is a legacy feature that should generally be avoided [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

### What is `__proto__`

Simply put, `__proto__` is just a propertyKey. And that's really all that you should see it as, because while there is a common behaviour among most builtin objects, It is by no means something that has to (or even should) behave in any specific manner.

#### Look at it as a regular getter/setter-pair

we can easily make any key behave in the same manner as `__proto__`:

```js
const provingAPoint = {
  get thisIsANormalKey () { return Reflect.getPrototypeOf(this) },
  set thisIsANormalKey (proto) { Reflect.setPrototypeOf(this, proto) }
}
```

And that's basically all that `__proto__` really is.

#### Always expect an object to differ from the default `__proto__` behaviour

If you are recieving an object from some API you should not expect `__proto__` to behave like it does in a default object. looking at the above example, it becomes clearer that it's not a reliable thing. We could for example do this:

```js
Reflect.defineProperty(provingAPoint, '__proto__', {
  get: () => { throw new Error('you are not getting my prototype like this') },
  set: () => { throw new Error('you will not set my prototype like this') }
})
```

Now if someone tries to access this property, they will get an error. it's now also readonly and can't be changed or deleted.

#### Use the proper methods instead

The global objects `Object` and `Reflect` both have the static methods `getPrototypeOf` and `setPrototypeOf` (not going to go into detail about `Reflect` and it's differences). If you're going to manipulate the prototype chain, use these

#### The single valid use for `__proto__` in todays Java/EcmaScript

There is one valid use that's suprisingly not well known. When you create an object literal, if you define a `__proto__` property on it, if it's value is an object or null, the resulting object will use that value as it's prototype

```js
// this can save you some of the annoyances of `Object.create(null, {...descriptors})`
const objectWithNullPrototype = {
  __proto__: null,
  propA: 'valueA',
  prop0: 'value0'
}

Object.getPrototypeOf(objectWithNullPrototype) // => `null`
// and again, don't extect any consistent behaviour of `__proto__` because:
objectWithNullPrototype.__proto__ // => `undefined`
```

### About `prototype`

The `prototype` property on a function defines what the is inherited when constructing an object

#### In short

A constructors `prototype` property is equal to the prototype of the object it constructs. eg:

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(new Array(12)) === Array.prototype // => true
// NOTE: don't do this, use literals or `Object.create`
Object.getPrototypeOf(new Object()) === Object.prototype // => true
Object.getPrototypeOf(new Map()) === Map.prototype // => true
```

### Java/EcmaScript is a **prototype-based** language

If you have any doubts on what this means, i highly recomend you google and read some articles about it, as misunderstanding (or not knowing) of the implications is a very common source of errors and confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The subject in question *__proto__* is deprecated and is, even when available, extremely slow and not recommended.

However, it is an accessor property[<sub>1</sub>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) which exposes the internal object through which it's accessed!

But if you read the following text by MDN, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) then it tells about how and why it was implemented even tho it was never meant to be added.

Long story short, while it is a getter/setter and does not directly connect to the object but in almost any scenario, do ***NOT*** use it

Comment: @Liam Wrong way round. `__proto__` is standardised (so that browsers that need to implement it for web-compatibility implement it consistently), but at the same time it is [explicitly deprecated in that standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061819/1048572) in favour of modern `Object.get/setPrototopeOf`.