# Why dunder prototypes are discouraged in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am new to javascript. Today I learned about prototypes. I want to know why dunder prototypes are discouraged and why we use Object.getPrototypeOf in its place?
I only noticed the difference in the way we write them.

Dunder prototype - objectname.prototype.function

new way that I learned - Object.getPrototypeOf(objectname)

Comment: `objectname.prototype` is **not** "dunder prototype". That term refers to `objectname.__proto__`. And [it's deprecated for good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061819/1048572) (such as [prototype pollution attacks](https://codeburst.io/what-is-prototype-pollution-49482fc4b638)) - it never was a good idea to access the prototype chain as if it was an ordinary property.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

> Warning: While Object.prototype.**proto** is supported today in most browsers, its existence and exact behavior has only been standardized in the ECMAScript 2015 specification as a legacy feature to ensure compatibility for web browsers. For better support, use Object.getPrototypeOf() instead.

Comment: Okay, just went through this. But, still not clear on the why of the above.

Comment: @RajatSharma I believe it's just that it's only supported as a legacy feature and it's not necessarily available in all browsers.